# Deserializing a XML file using Java and Simple XML serialiser/deserialiser

Tags: java, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

These are the errors i'm getting. 
I understand that there is a problem with my schema and that it cant find the student element. But why cant it find the element is beyond me. Ideally i would like this to work so that i can get the students name, grades and courses to calculate the weighted average grade and to sort the students by name. What i would like to know is what am i doing wrong. I followed the tutorials on [Simple XML serializers website](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) but i'm stumped on why it doesn't work. Also the line number it gives there does not lead to anything in my code.

Any help is well appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'students' does not have a match in class Student at line 2
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:527)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Injector.read(Composite.java:1433)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:426)
    at Deserializer.main(Deserializer.java:17)
```

This is my XML im trying to deserialize.

```
<uni>
<students>

   <student>
    <studentName>Joe</studentName>
        <studentCourses>
            <course name="XML" grade="2" />
            <course name="Java" grade="5" />
        </studentCourses>
   </student>

   <student>
    <studentName>Jane</studentName>
        <studentCourses>
            <course name="XML" grade="3" />
            <course name="Java" grade="5" />
        </studentCourses>
   </student>

</students>
</uni>
```

My Java classes that should fit the XML schema.

Uni class

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="uni")
public class Uni {

    @Element(name="students")
    public Students students;

    public Uni(){}
}
```

Students class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.*;


public class Students {

    @ElementList(name="student", entry="students", inline=true)
    public List<Student> student;

    public Students(){}

    public List getProperties(){
        return student;
    }
```

Student class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

//@Element
public class Student {
        @Element(name="studentName")
        public String studentName;

        @ElementList(name="studentCourses")
        public List<StudentCourses> studentCourses;

        //public Student (){}

        public Student(String studentName){
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }

        public String getStudentName(){
            return this.studentName;
        }
    }
```

StudentCourse class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

@Element
public class StudentCourses {

    @ElementList(name="studentCourses")
    public List<Course> course;
}
```

Course class

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;


public class Course {
    @Element(name="course", required=false)
    public String course;

    @Attribute(name="name")
    public String courseName;

    @Attribute(name="grade")
    public int grade;

    //default constructor
    public Course () {}

    public  String getCourseName (String courseName){
        return this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public int getCourseGrade (int courseGrade){
        return this.grade = courseGrade;
    }
}
```

Deserializer class

```
import java.io.File;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;





public class Deserializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File result = new File("stud.xml");

        Student student = serializer.read(Student.class, result);
        //Students stud = serializer.read(Students.class, result);

            System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
            //System.out.println(stud.getProperties());



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file contains a `<uni>`, but you're trying to parse it as if it were a single `Student`:

```
    Student student = serializer.read(Student.class, result);
    System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
```

You've already defined an object corresponding to the `<uni>`, which may contain many zero or many students. Parse with:

```
    Uni uni = serializer.read(Uni.class, result);

    for (Student student : uni.students.student) {
        System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay but the exception remains the same.
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'student' does not have a match in class Students at line 4

Comment: Your `@ElementList` specifies `entry="students"`, when the XML element in your document is `student`.

Comment: Thanks Joe ! It helped me get the student names out. Could you explain your thought process behind all of it ? because now i would like to get the course attributes from the studentCourses element and i think the problem is some what the same.

Comment: The error message you're getting refers to a class, a line in the XML file and an element that's been encountered. All I can suggest is focusing on those points and seeing how the parser's expectation differs from what you've defined.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help and advice Joe !
i do have some follow up questions that are kind of off topic. They include getting attribute values and mapping them to a specific student element but i guess i'll ask a new question.

Comment: helps in my situation